# Use a JS function in a dynamic page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that is being generated when this page is called and I wrote a function to shrink the links in the table to the last 4 chars.
[image: table page 1]

```
return function() {

var f = function() {};

f.version = "1";

f.afterDraw = function() {

    var txt = document.querySelector('[id^=data-table] > tbody ').getElementsByTagName('a');

    for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
      txt[i].textContent = txt[i].textContent.toString().slice(-4);

    }

};
return f;
}();
```

My problems is that if I go to page 3: 
[image: table page 3]
the links appear entirely and are not shrink, of course this happens for every page, except page one that was actually loaded. 
What am I doing wrong in my function?

Comment: What is your function to switch between pages? If you are using an event handler you may need to delegate your event. Does the same happen if you visit the third page url in the address bar?

Comment: I dont have a function to switch pages, because the code I am adding it's inside a style editor embedded into the web application

Comment: You have a function that immediately executes, does it execute again when you change pages? If those elements on subsequent pages are not already in the DOM, you will need to run the function after every page switch.

Comment: Probably it doesnt. But when I go to the next page in the table the page doesnt refresh, only the table get refreshed. How can I add a listener or something like this to execute this function again?

Comment: You can add a click event listener. in jquery `$(document).on('click', '.CLASS-OF-PAGE-NUMBER', function(){ //run function again});` EDIT for this you may want to name your function.

Comment: Is it possible to use the selector instead of the class?

Comment: Yes anything to identify which element you are clicking